# REST API - GetUserByEmail best approach for get route

Tags: c#, rest

I am trying to follow a pattern with my api routes.

These are all GET requests

```
/users                         -- get all users
/users/{userId}                -- get user by id
/users/email/{email}           -- get user by email
```

Obv. that third one is a problem since the last part of the route will have something like /user@domain.com, thus the route is not processed since it thinks I am trying to go to a different domain (ex:  `http://localhost/users/email/me@microsoft.com`

I know that I can make this work with a POST, I know I can make this work with some other combination like /users/{email}/gedderdone

... but I am trying to follow a pattern that is consistent for all resources.

ie:

```
/people/{id}
/people/name/{name}
/people/ssn/{ssn}
```

How should I format the REST endpoint for getting a user by their email address?  I do want to use a GET as I am 'getting' the user.

Thanks :-)

Comment: You should use `GET` for idempotent requests, not simply for "getting" stuff.

Comment: Can you try using the url: `http://localhost/users/email/me%40microsoft.com`?

Comment: @Digital, it was the .COM that was causing the route to miss, not the @ symbol :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be afraid to use parameters in your requests

e.g

```
/users
/users/{userid}
/users/email?address=me@microsoft.com
```

personally I'd be inclined to just treat users as a "pure" resource and differentiate the ways of getting a user (apart from by it's unchanging, unique ID via `/users/1`, etc) via parameters:

```
/users/?by=email&value=me@microsoft.com
/users/?by=ssn&value=123345
/users/?by=shoesize&value=10
```

There's nothing in REST that says you have to identify a resource purely by route values; if you stick with pure route value patterns , and find you need to retrieve a user by multiple fields, you'll end up having to code crazy routes like `users/department/development/project/14567/location/dublin` which sounds cool until someone wants to call it by location then by project, then by department, etc.

Comment: hahaha - yes trying to be RESTful can really get you thinking crazy after a while.  I somehow forgot I can use parameters - now i have to review all of my routes again.

"personally I'd be inclined to just treat users as a "pure" resource and differentiate the ways of getting a user (apart from by it's unchanging, unique ID via /users/1, etc) via parameters:"
-YES, I somehow lost my mind, this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

C#-HTMLEncode or Javascript-escape your parameters. That should help.

Answer (score 0):

An "@" sign is a reserved sign according to [RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). Therefore you must pass it percent-encoded as %40 - anything else is invalid.